# Return Largest Numbers in 3D Array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

What approach is best for returning an array of max numbers for this array in JS?

```
[[[1,2,4],[3,4,6]],[[33,55,66],[99,4,55]]]
```

I want the result to be `[4,6,66,99]`

Comment: please add your approach. what goes wrong?

Comment: I can do it for 2D array with loop through but I don't have any idea for this. should I use 3 loop?

Comment: @Amirhossein Yes, using three nested loops and finding the maximum inside the innermost loop would work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested `map` and the spread operator with `max`.

```js
a=[[[1,2,4],[3,4,6]],[[33,55,66],[99,4,55]]];
document.write(a.map((a)=>a.map((a)=>Math.max(...a))));
```

Comment: Thank you JMP. Very professional approach!